# How can i move a test run from one test set to another in Quality Center?

Tags: hp-quality-center

In Quality Center, I want to move a test run with Passed/Failed status from one test set to another, copying its run history as well.

Please help, how can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy single test case from one test set to another , though you can copy the entire test set and paste it and then delete the unwanted test cases. That seems to be the best possible solution as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

The ALM Client will not let you move a test run from one test instance to another, nor a test instance to another test set.

You would need to copy the details of the run into the new set either manually, or basically do the same thing through the OTAClient API.

It is highly recommended not to update the database directly.  However, we had the same issue and ONLY IF YOU KNOW THE DATA MODEL AND KNOW EXACTLY what you are doing, you can change the ID of the TC_TESTCYCL_ID in the RUN table to the new one to move it.  It has been a while since I did this so you need to check the other tables and make sure this is the only ID that you need to change.  If you really want to do this I can look into it further.